# Flutter: Text is cut a little bit in vertical direction in NodeExpansionTile widget

Tags: flutter, listtile

Text is cut a little bit in vertical direction in NodeExpansionTile widget.

It happened only on huawei mate 30. Other device is working fine

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.select<CompanyViewModel, Companies?>((CompanyViewModel model) => model.selected);
    context.select<CompanyViewModel, bool?>((CompanyViewModel model) => model.selected.isSelected);
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return NodeExpansionTile(
        initiallyExpanded: company.isOpen,
        isSelected: company.isSelected,
        childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        maintainState: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (company.hasChildren!)
            _CompanyListBody(
              companies: company.children!,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            )
        ],
        leading: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SvgPicture.asset(
                context.read<CompanyViewModel>().getLeadingPath(company),
                width: 20,
                height: 20,)
            ]),
        title: Text((company.code ?? I10n.of(context).noDataText)+' '+(company.name ?? I10n.of(context).noDataText),
          style: company.isSelected
              ? themeData.textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(color: themeData.primaryColor,fontWeight:  FontWeight.w400,)
              : themeData.textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith(fontWeight:  FontWeight.w400),),
        onExpansionChanged: (bool value) {
          context.read<CompanyViewModel>().changeSelected(company);
        }
    );
  }
```

Any light to this issue?

many thanks?